# Can we put windows form inside Tab Controls in C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application, tabcontrol, windows

Can we put more then one windows forms inside Tab Controls in a single form in C# Windows Application ??

For Example, Is it the right way to implement it or should we use User Control?.

```
  Form2 frm = new Form2();
  frm.TopLevel = false;
  frm.Visible = true;
  frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
  frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(frm);
```

Comment: [UserControls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036481/user-control-in-windows-forms-application)

Comment: You should look into [user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Designing your forms as `user controls` separately - then inserting them into your various tabs - is definitely a better way to organise your code.

Comment: I had a problem similar to this and I used "partial classes" to split up different pieces of the c# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not and don't need to use Windows Forms, but what you can do is using:

- [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) that holds all controls of the current tab
- [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx) control
- [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e63s4df3.aspx) control
- [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx.aspx) Control to destribute position of the child contorls based on some proprtion, so your UI looks equaly good on different screen sizes and resolutions.

Having those ones you can create UIs in your VS design, so it's easy to manage changes. 
If the quantity of the controls and possible options, so Tabs, is really big, you may consider also an option to load them dynamically. But in this case correct allignemnt and maintanability of the project becomes harder.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could benefit from moving the functionality in your separate tabs into a UserControl.

A UserControl is a nice way of separating functionality out from your main form.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really forces you to put 15 tabs code into a single c# file. You can use partial class principle to split a single class to many source files. You can also split code to more than one class - Visual Studio is just a tool for you, it is not your director. You don't need to behave like VS dictates, it covers just most common cases and you can do better class designs in special situations like yours.

And yes, you can put whatever to tabs, I mean any CONTROL object from any other class. You can also put there a form object - in cases when your form objects are already created, because underlying Windows API allows this.